# If variable first character is dot remove it

Tags: php

Looking for something simple error proof.
I got `$keyword` variable I want to filter it 
with if first character is '.' remove it if not keep it as it is. I'm afraid to try it on my own because I have created such code before and it ruined the whole thing sometimes removing dots in the middle of the text... so it's important only the first character if exists

Comment: str_replace('.', '', $keyword);

Comment: @MarkVoidale That would remove any `.`

Comment: @MarkVoidale: no, this will replace all dots.

Comment: @MarkVoidale do you want to remove all dots at the begining, for example if it's `"...string"` to become `"string"`?

Comment: @MarkoD I only have 2 cases .string or string there will never be ..string so if it's .string i want to make it string if it's string do not touch

Comment: @MarkVoidale but if there was such case?

Comment: If you explained exactly what you're really doing I think you would get more helpful answers. Trimming file extensions? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
$keyword = (substr($keyword, 0, 1) === '.' ? substr($keyword, 1) : $keyword);
```

Essentially the same, less terse, but perhaps clearer way:

```
if (substr($keyword, 0, 1) === '.')
    {
    $keyword = substr($keyword, 1);
    }
```

Using a regular expression:

```
$keyword = preg_replace('{^\.}', '', $keyword, 1);
```

Comment: finally! I think this is what I need just to be sure: 1. It will check the first character only? If it's . remove it if not do not touch the string right? (Because I might have dots in the string)

Comment: @MarkVoidale: Yes, all of these methods only remove the first character if it's a dot

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I need. I know for a fact I can have only 2 cases and this covers it perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($keyword[0] === '.') {
    $keyword = substr($keyword, 1);
}
```

Comment: can you explain the code? Is this checking the first character only?

Comment: Only correct answer according to the spec.

Comment: @MarkVoidale, on the first line, it checks if the first character in the string is a `.`. If so, then the next line removes the first dot from the string.

Comment: No point using strpos() to search the entire string when we're only interested in the first character.

Comment: @rid how about this case with this code? I have this: .string but what if i have string.string.string? Will it remove the first occurrence of the dot? I do have dots in the variable after

Comment: @MarkVoidale, only the first one will be removed, and only if it exists at the first position.

Comment: @rid: And if the first character is _not_ a dot, strpos() will merrily search the entire rest of the string

Comment: @CoreXii, true. Answer updated for efficiency, thanks for the observation.

Comment: @rid now the updated codes looks like it thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all dots at the begining of a keyword.

```
$keyword = ltrim($keyword, '.');
```

Comment: This would remove more dots as well.

Comment: But what if the string starts with '..'? It is not clear that they should both be removed right?

Comment: i asked him for clarification

Comment: I only have 2 cases .string or string there will never be ..string so if it's .string i want to make it string if it's string do not touch

Comment: and **if** it's '..string'. hypotetically speaking?

Comment: downvoters, care to explain?

Comment: if it's ..string lets make it string but I will not have that case

Comment: @MarkVoidale please edit your question and clarify that...